# Are there any survey tools that are optimized to render correctly on mobile devices?

Tags: mobile, tools, measuring, user-research

My company would like to run a NPS survey off of our Mobile experience (app and website), are there any tools that will work well with mobile screens? We use Vovici, cvent and surveymonkey in house already and nothing is exactly what we are looking for. It would be nice to use a link to launch a mobile ready survey formatted to the right screen size that doesn't use tiny radio buttons that can be hard to select.

Answer (score 1):

Our product, [CustomerSure](http://www.customersure.com/) may fit the bill. Strictly speaking, we're a tool to gather and act upon customer feedback, rather than a general-purpose surveying solution like SurveyMonkey but we feel this offers a couple of advantages:

1. Our [NPS-compatible surveys](http://www.customersure.com/tour/#sect_survey) are deliberately very short and easy to complete (we've spent a lot of time on the experience), meaning better response rates.
2. Feedback and scores land in a tool which has been designed to encourage staff collaboration and actionable responses, rather than sitting neglected in a spreadsheet somewhere.

Our standard survey is clean, attractive and is easy to interact with on a touchscreen.

Apologies if this sounds in any way sales-y or spammy, it's not my intent, it just happens that our company produces product which seems to answer your question! A free trial is available if you'd like, or get in touch if you'd like more help. (I'll probably edit this answer to improve it if there's anything important I've missed).

Answer (score 0):

I am updating with the answer we went with...

The upgraded version of Vovici allow surveys to be rendered in Mobile HTML. This has solved our problem. However, OpinionMeter also has a decent product that would allow us to do the same.